# javascript for loop adding issue - creating custom jQuery paging

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

Need a hand with some javascript and maybe its a friday thing, but im stuck...

I am making a custom jQuery carousel and im tring to make dynamic paging.

To simplify the issue (have added hard coded values), at the moment this code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 $('.paging').append('<a href="#" rel="0">Test</a>');
}
```

outputs:

```
<a href="#" rel="0">Test</a>
<a href="#" rel="0">Test</a>
<a href="#" rel="0">Test</a>
```

Whereas I need the code to output like:

```
<a href="#" rel="0">Test</a>
<a href="#" rel="200">Test</a>
<a href="#" rel="400">Test</a>
```

I can I adjust the for statement above so that it adds 200 everytime it loops through?

Any help would be much appreiated.

A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it more easily with the [`$(html, props)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) notation and [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $('<a />', { href: '#', text: 'Test', rel: i*200 }).appendTo('.paging');    
}
```

[You cant test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WfHNy/1/).  If you're looping through a lot though, I'd advise caching the `.paging` selector, like this:

```
var p = $('.paging');
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $('<a />', { href: '#', text: 'Test', rel: i*200 }).appendTo(p);    
}
```

Comment: +1 for the syntax.. I like the convention, but haven't gotten myself around to using it yet.. need some self-enforcing..

Comment: Didn't know about that one ( $(html, props) ). It's sexy and I guess more readable the more properties of the element depends on variables. +1 to you!

Comment: @Simen - also keep in mind for many scenarios it's much safer, for example the text is sanitized before being set, quotes get encoded so they won't screw up your HTML, etc...always prefer the DOM method of creating if at all possible :)

Comment: @Nick, the DOM is ok for small/medium appends. But not when things get heavy on the client side. If you use a JS templating engine you get the speed and a correct HTML.

Comment: @Mic - It's fine for large appends as well, use a document fragment if needed in those cases.  It's all about using it correctly :)

Comment: @Nick, nah... even with document fragment ^L^

Comment: @Mic - show me a slow append...remember that jQuery caches and clones the document fragment used in creation, and cloning is faster than re-creating the element from HTML repeatedly :)  DOM manipulation is not only as fast, it's *faster*, you just have to do it properly.  Things change over 10 years, what used to be slow isn't necessarily the case anymore, don't believe the rumors, test it yourself.

Comment: @Nick, I did some serious testing, while building a template engine 2yrs ago. And there was no comparisons. Safari was at that time better, but all were pretty good with `innerHTML`. Not to mention the still present and ugly IE.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = '';
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 str +='<a href="#" rel="' + i * 200 + '">Test</a>';
}

$('.paging').append(str)
```

Appending once should be better for performances.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   var rel = i * 200;
   $('.paging').append('<a href="#" rel="' + rel + '">Test</a>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

multiply the counter (`i`) by 200

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 $('.paging').append('<a href="#" rel="'+i*200+'">Test</a>');
}
```